# Quiz how to show correct and wrong answer in result activity

Tags: android

I would like to know how to show what is wrong and correct answers got in the quiz. Like:

1.A-Wrong

2.A-Wrong

3.A-Correct

4.A-Correct

5.A-Correct

Result Activity:

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    RatingBar bar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    bar.setNumStars(5);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult);
    Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/hvd.otf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int score= b.getInt("score");
    bar.setRating(score);
    switch (score)
    {
    case 1:
    case 2: tv.setText("Study Harder");
    break;
    case 3:
    case 4:tv.setText("Wow, you're good");
    break;
    case 5:tv.setText("Are you a geius?!");
    break;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_result, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What's wrong with this so far?

Comment: @Claud nothing is wrong here I just wanna know how can i display the answers user answered in the quiz

Comment: Well it seems like you are just getting in the score from the Bundle. You also have to pass in the answers and then display them using a textview or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing in my project. Where i have maintained a `Linked List` holding the object of a class having properties and the methods to access those properties as: question, its options, and the answer selected by the user.

With this structure I was able to show the complete review of the attempts of the questions by the user. Hope this idea will help you.

**example:**

```
class questionStructure{
    String Question, Answer;
    ArrayList<String> options;
    public questionStructure(){
        Question = "";
        Answer = "";
        options = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void setQuestion(String Question){
        this.Question = Question;
    }

    ....
    //same for other properties.

}
```

and store the object of this class to the link list. Why Linked list, because it give a flexible approach for traversing to back and forward while traversing the answers of each questions one by one.